# Ruby on Rails - Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

**Ruby on rails**
if i submit my create auction form, i want to show in my facebook. how to do that?
someone said using OAuth to connect it with my facebook account..
please help me...

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question... this is like "I want a huge house... how do I do that?"

Comment: This is a badly worded question, but there's a kernel of a question there. I think the gist of it is "I want to put things on Facebook using my Rails app. Where do I start?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used oauth2 gem for similar thing, here's a simple example on how to connect with it to facebook:
http://wiki.github.com/intridea/oauth2/rails-23-webserver-example
(but you don't really need a separate controller for that)

Also, see 'Requesting Extended Permissions' section here, you'll need 'publish_stream' permission to post content:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you might try and read up on the Facebooker API and then install the Gem (or the plugin, wichever suits you) and build from there.

http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/